# Remove only leading or trailing carriage returns

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I'm dumbfounded that this question has not been asked meaningfully already. How does one go about creating an equivalent function in SQL like `LTRIM` or `RTRIM` for carriage returns and line feeds ONLY at the start or end of a string.

Obviously `REPLACE(REPLACE(@MyString,char(10),''),char(13),'')` removes ALL carriage returns and new line feeds. Which is NOT what I'm looking for. I just want to remove leading or trailing ones.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Find the first character that is *not* `CHAR(13)` or `CHAR(10)` and subtract its position from the string's length.

**LTRIM()**

```
SELECT RIGHT(@MyString,LEN(@MyString)-PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+']%',@MyString)+1)
```

**RTRIM()**

```
SELECT LEFT(@MyString,LEN(@MyString)-PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+']%',REVERSE(@MyString))+1)
```

Comment: This is good, but fails if the string only contains CRLF characters. PATINDEX returns 0 in this case, so the whole string is returned.

Answer (score 17):

Following functions are enhanced types of `trim` functions you can use. Copied from [sqlauthority.com](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/10/sql-server-2008-enhenced-trim-function-remove-trailing-spaces-leading-spaces-white-space-tabs-carriage-returns-line-feeds/)

These functions remove trailing spaces, leading spaces, white space, tabs, carriage returns, line feeds etc.

**Trim Left**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LTrimX(@str VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @trimchars VARCHAR(10)
SET @trimchars = CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(32)
IF @str LIKE '[' + @trimchars + ']%' SET @str = SUBSTRING(@str, PATINDEX('%[^' + @trimchars + ']%', @str), LEN(@str))
RETURN @str
END
```

**Trim Right**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RTrimX(@str VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @trimchars VARCHAR(10)
SET @trimchars = CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(32)
IF @str LIKE '%[' + @trimchars + ']'
SET @str = REVERSE(dbo.LTrimX(REVERSE(@str)))
RETURN @str
END
```

**Trim both Left and Right**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TrimX(@str VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN dbo.LTrimX(dbo.RTrimX(@str))
END
```

**Using function**

```
SELECT dbo.TRIMX(@MyString)
```

If you do use these functions you might also consider changing from `varchar` to `nvarchar` to support more encodings.

Answer (score 7):

In SQL Server 2017 you can use the [`TRIM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to remove specific characters from beginning and end, in one go:

```
WITH testdata(str) AS (
    SELECT CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' test ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
)
SELECT
    str,
    TRIM(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(9) + ' ' FROM str) AS [trim cr/lf/tab/space],
    TRIM(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) FROM str) AS [trim cr/lf],
    TRIM(' ' FROM str) AS [trim space]
FROM testdata
```

Result:

[image: result - non-printable characters replaced with visible alternates]

Note that the last example (trim space) does nothing as expected since the spaces are in the middle.

Comment: This example shows capabilities of the 2017 **TRIM()** function that would not have been obvious to the casual developer.  As he has shown the function accepts parameters in a syntax I have not seen anywhere before.
`TRIM ( [ characters FROM ] string )`
Here is a sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/25c63/2) if you want to try it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

## Here's an example you may run:

I decided to cast the results as an `Xml` value, so when you click on it, you will be able to view the Carriage Returns.

```
DECLARE @CRLF Char(2) = (CHAR(0x0D) + CHAR(0x0A))
DECLARE @String VarChar(MAX) = @CRLF + @CRLF + '    Hello' + @CRLF + 'World  ' + @CRLF + @CRLF
--Unmodified String:
SELECT CAST(@String as Xml)[Unmodified]
--Remove Trailing Whitespace (including Spaces).
SELECT CAST(LEFT(@String, LEN(REPLACE(@String, @CRLF, '  '))) as Xml)[RemoveTrailingWhitespace]
--Remove Leading Whitespace (including Spaces).
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(@String, LEN(REVERSE(REPLACE(@String, @CRLF, '  ')))) as Xml)[RemoveLeadingWhitespace]
--Remove Leading & Trailing Whitespace (including Spaces).
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@String, LEN(REPLACE(@String, ' ', '_')) - LEN(REVERSE(REPLACE(@String, @CRLF, '  '))) + 1, LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@String, @CRLF, '  '))))) as Xml)[RemoveAllWhitespace]
--Remove Only Leading and Trailing CR/LF's (while still preserving all other Whitespace - including Spaces). - 04/06/2016 - MCR.
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@String, PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+']%',@String), LEN(REPLACE(@String, ' ', '_')) - PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+']%',@String) + 1 - PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+']%', REVERSE(@String)) + 1) as Xml)[RemoveLeadingAndTrailingCRLFsOnly]
```

Remember to remove the Cast-to-Xml, as this was done just as a Proof-of-Concept to show it works.

## How is this better than the currently Accepted Answer?

At first glance this may appear to use more Functions than the Accepted Answer.
However, this is not the case.
If you combine both approaches listed in the Accepted Answer (to remove *both* Trailing and Leading whitespace), you will either have to make two passes updating the Record, *or* copy all of one Logic into the other (everywhere `@String` is listed), which would cause way more function calls and become even more difficult to read.

Comment: And to remove all of them (tab, CR/LF, spaces), leading and trailing, we do: `SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@String, PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(32)+']%',@String), LEN(REPLACE(@String, ' ', '_')) - PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(32)+']%',@String) + 1 - PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(32)+']%', REVERSE(@String)) + 1) as Xml)[RemoveLeadingAndTrailingCRLFsOnly]`

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck using `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2` and so basing my functions on @sqluser's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36191186/2571982) I came up with the below. This will return an empty string if the string only contains the characters to be trimmed.

The bit that threw me was the pattern for PATINDEX must be included between `%` characters, which for a while I was thinking of as the same wildcard in a `LIKE` statement but which I now believe is just the syntax to denote a pattern, though I may be wrong!

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ExtendedLTRIM](@string_to_trim VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tab CHAR(1) = CHAR(9);
    DECLARE @line_feed CHAR(1) = CHAR(10);
    DECLARE @carriage_return CHAR(1) = CHAR(13);
    DECLARE @space CHAR(1) = CHAR(32);

    DECLARE @characters_to_trim VARCHAR(10)
    SET @characters_to_trim = @tab + @line_feed + @carriage_return + @space

    IF @string_to_trim LIKE '[' + @characters_to_trim + ']%'
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @first_non_trim_character INT = PATINDEX('%[^' + @characters_to_trim + ']%', @string_to_trim);

        IF @first_non_trim_character = 0 RETURN '';

        RETURN SUBSTRING(@string_to_trim, @first_non_trim_character, 8000)
    END

    RETURN @string_to_trim
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

To trim characters from a pre-defined list you'll want to create the following UDF (should work in 2008R2 and above).

Handles both sides in a single pass and doesn't care if it's a CRLF, LFCR (yep, seen that abomination more than once), bare LF or a bunch of spaces.

is easy to extend to e.g. add additional parameters to do LTRIM/RTRIM only, or a full purge (that last bit is simpler to do in 2017 by incorporating STRING_AGG, but perfectly doable in 2008R2); as a matter of fact this is a simplified version of something I use to do all those things. If anybody is interested then let me know and I'll update:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnTrimHarder
(
    @String VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE
        @Start INT,
        @Len INT,
        @Chars CHAR(5) = CONCAT(
            CHAR(9), -- TAB
            CHAR(10), -- LF
            CHAR(13), -- CR
            ' '
        ), -- List of invalid characters
        @Return VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    
    IF @String NOT LIKE '%[^' + @Chars + ']%' -- If string contains only invalid characters
    OR COALESCE(@String, '') = '' -- Optional addition for NULL handling
        RETURN @Return
    ELSE
    BEGIN -- Create a "table" of characters with ordinals, calculate the start of string and its length, then return the substring 
        WITH CTE AS (
            SELECT 1 AS n
            UNION ALL
            SELECT n + 1
            FROM CTE
            WHERE n < LEN(@String)
        )
        SELECT 
            @Start = MIN(n),
            @Len = 1 + MAX(n) - MIN(n)
        FROM CTE 
        WHERE SUBSTRING(@String, n, 1) NOT LIKE '[' + @Chars + ']';
        
        SET @Return = SUBSTRING(@String, @Start, @Len)
    END

    RETURN @Return

END
GO
```