# How to search for carriage return character in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix, awk

I am struggling with this issue. I am trying to enclose my data in \001 and remove the odd character out for etl purpose in sql server. But if you see the last line, there seems to be a carriage return character, but does not work when i try to remove it. I have tried replace(replace(column,char(10),''),char(13),'')). The below is when I do a less of the column, but do not know what the character is. has anyone experienced this issue before?

Any suggestions welcome.

^A011111^A

^A012345^A

^A001231231^A

^A000213123123112^A

^A

^A

please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Remove only leading or trailing carriage returns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035836/sql-remove-only-leading-or-trailing-carriage-returns)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script.

```
   SELECT REPLACE(column,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'')
```

see one sample scenario.

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(50)=CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'Hello'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'world'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)

 SELECT LEN(@input) --OUTPUT : 16
```

Removing all the carriage symbol

```
 SELECT LEN(REPLACE(@input,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'')) --OUTPUT : 10
```

If you want remove carriage symbol from right end of a string,use the below query

```
SELECT  @input=LEFT(@input,LEN(@input)-PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+']%',REVERSE(@input))+1)
SELECT LEN(@input) --OUTPUT : 14
```

If you wanted to remove carriage symbol from right end of a string,use the below query

```
SELECT @input=RIGHT(@input,LEN(@input)-PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+']%',@input)+1)
SELECT LEN(@input) --OUTPUT : 12
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

select replace(replace(@input,'^A',''),char(13),'')