# How to trim all spaces and new lines only of the right side

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Probably it is very easy but for some reason, I can't manage to do it.

The problem is when I remove all the spaces\new lines with `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(10)` and `RTRIM` it removes all of the spaces and new lines in both directions.

```
DECLARE @txt NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @txt = '

Some Text

';
```

Expected Result:

```
@txt = '

Some Text';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Remove only leading or trailing carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035836/sql-remove-only-leading-or-trailing-carriage-returns)

Comment: It's *not* easy. SQL isn't a string manipulation language. Ideally, data cleaning should be performed *before* inserting the data in the database. Before SQL Server 2016 you'd have to use a very complex query or an external program written eg in C#, to clean text like this. In SQL Server 2016 you can use an R script too. SQl Server 2017 adds Python support as well

Comment: Have you even tried to Google this problem????  There are tons of references on the web.

Comment: @Eric tons of very complicated and/or slow solutions. The OP is asking to replace *newlines* at the end of the string. That would be easy with a regex. It's not easy with SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such tasks it will be nice to implement SQL CLR function that introduce regex functionality in SQL Server. For example:

```
DECLARE @txt NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @txt = '

Some Text


';

SELECT [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexReplace] (@txt, '[\s\n]+$', '');
```

You can find more information about how to create such function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692940/remove-weird-characters-a-with-hat-from-sql-server-varchar-column/31693412#31693412).

For newer version of SQL Server (starting from SQL Server 2016) you have options to use `R` for such operations like it is mention in the comments.

Anyway, I am recommended to read about SQL CLR objects that can be created (functions, triggers, types, aggregates) as you can solve various of tasks using .net.